# How do I setup the Application Settings by code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, application-settings, .net-framework-version

I'm using Visual Studio 2017, and I have a boat load of settings I'm adding. It's kind of a pain in the neck to add them by this Settings.settings table in VS. Is there a better way?

Comment: . NET Framework or .NET Core? (Former uses `app.config` or `web.config`, latter uses `appsettings.json` with very different APIs).

Comment: You can use ConfigurationManager to read and write to the app.config file programatically. I store my sqlite connection string using this method.

Comment: @Richard .Net Framework sorry. i should start adding this in tags. will fix. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the option of not using the default settings application behavior, or if you can use another bahavior in addition to it, perhaps it may help you:

[How to create a hand-made application settings file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58219475/how-to-change-the-location-of-the-application-exe-config-file-in-net#58220768)

In this case, this may help you too:

[How to initialize user app data and document path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58202091/how-to-keep-the-last-used-folder-and-put-it-in-a-textbox-when-a-form-opens/58202264#58202264)

So you can for example put this settings file in the user app data folder or anywhere you want.

Comment: this looks like it could be a nice solution. great information here. gracias.