# Reading config values from Project A into Project B

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

I have 2 projects in the same solution: One is a windows project and the other one is a console application. They both have 2 app.config in each project.

I am trying to read the values from the .vshost.exe.config from windows application(Project 1) into the Console application (Project 2).

I am finding it difficult to get the path of this config files read into the 2nd project.

Any pointers in achieving this, would be greatly helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically I would reconsider you design - settings of particular project should be able for reading only within that project.

E.g. if you need some info (say getting some data from path "xxx" which is stored in **#1 Project config file** then your **#1 Project** should have a public API for doing that and **#2 Project** should only use that API)

If there is still a strong necessity of doing that than you should better create a new project for that or store those configs in database.

Comment: Thanks @fox112358, followed your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The .NET Framework behavior about config files is one for an assembly per version.

The path is internally managed by the framework in:

```
UserAppData\Company\[AssemblyName]_Url_[some obfuscated id per version]
```

If you want to share config, you can create a hand-made application settings file like this:

[How to create a hand-made application settings file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58219475/how-to-change-the-location-of-the-application-exe-config-file-in-net#58220768)

[How to initialize user app data and document path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58202091/how-to-keep-the-last-used-folder-and-put-it-in-a-textbox-when-a-form-opens/58202264#58202264)

For example you can store it in `UserAppData\Company\SomeFixedName\` or anything you want.

Comment: Thanks @Oliver Rogier, will try your steps and the link, to see how to achieve this.